# FME - merge using data from table (distance of line)

Tags: line, merge, fme-form

I have line_1 which is build from two elements (a,b).
0 means start of line. First (a) has 20 m, second (b) 30 m. I have table with distance of these lines and records are separate (example on screen). I need to merge them and it should looks like: 0, 20 (first verse) and 0, 30 (second verse).

I tried for example Aggregator, AttributeSplitter, ListSorter, ListConcatenator and ListExploder but after using these formulas I get in one verse: 0,0,20,30.

[image]
[image]

[image]

Data from 1 and 2 is connected. On 380 distance we have -42, on 0 we have -50.... They have to be sorted in order.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you're trying to do by clicking [edit]. Are you trying to join the two lines together? Have you tried the LineJoiner transformer? How does the other table come into this?

Comment: Yes, I tried linejoner also.
 It's only one element of my big process.
I have points on that lines and I need to now where are they. (distance of lines)